# In Ruby what is the meaning of colon after identifier in a Hash?

Tags: ruby, syntax, hash

I'm learning about Factory Girl and I saw this code:

```
factory :post do
  association :author, factory: :user, last_name: "Writely"
end
```

why do `factory` and `last_name` have a colon at their end?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The colon in this context denotes a literal Hash.

`factory` is the `Hash` key, `:user` is the value.

The alternative syntax is `:factory => :user`. They mean the same thing.

Comment: Note that the non-hashrocket syntax was added in Ruby 1.9, and doesn't exist in earlier versions.

Comment: So in this context the `:` is `=>`?

Comment: Yes, it's just a new way to write Hashes that was introduced in Ruby 1.9, possibly because it is slightly more concise than the => syntax.

Comment: @Arman Not exactly, using the `:` always makes the key a literal symbol, which doesn't happen with the `=>`. If you want to use anything other than a literal symbol (variable, string, etc.) as the key you have to use the `=>`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, @OzBandit I'm confused. I thought if you used the `:` before the key then that key is a literal. Are you saying for hash keys having the colon before or after has the same effect?

Comment: @Arman Yup, as in the answers here: `:foo => "bar"`, `foo: "bar"`, and `"foo": "bar"` are equivalent, and different from `"foo" => "bar` and `foo => "bar"`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Correct! I always think that works because `:"foo"` does, but `"foo": "bar"` is indeed a syntax error, and since I rarely ever actually try to use it like that, I've yet to fix the mistake in my brain `:[`.

Comment: Since `:` is already used by symbols, using that to identify hash keys seems like a big mistake. It's nowhere near as flexible as the arrow and causes confusion when you're forced to switch to the arrow syntax because of limitations. Rails started using it in some of their configuration files and it's not helping anyone still on 1.8.7 either deliberately or for lack of knowing about other options.

Answer (score 17):

Ruby 1.8 syntax:

```
:factory => :user
```

Ruby 1.9 syntax:

```
factory: :user
```

Note that the Ruby 1.8 syntax works in 1.9 also.

Comment: What was the rationale behind adding this new syntax? I think it reads worse than the rockets/arrows, which are commonly understood to represent mappings.

Comment: I'm uncertain why it was changed. I googled around and can't find any obvious discussion on it. If you find some background pls post it, i'm interested. Thanks1

Comment: This change may have something to do with how Javascript and perhaps other languages handle object literal notation.

For example, in JavaScript, we can do:
    `var person = {
        name: "John",
        age: 42,
        married: false
    }`

so really, when we're passing `factory: :user`, what we're really doing is passing `{factory: :user}`, also written as `{:factory => :user}`. The 1.9 syntax is intended to make it easier to do something like `{factory: "user"}`

Comment: I find that with fewer extra characters it reads better, especially since it makes the screen less 'busy.' (It's also faster to type, but that's not as big a deal since developers spend far more time reading than typing code.)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right. There was some speculation regarding the rationale behind this new syntax. This change may have something to do with how Javascript and perhaps other languages handle object literal notation. A need was felt, perhaps, to bring ruby more in-line with how these languages handle object creation.

For example, in JavaScript, we can do:

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 42,
    married: false
}
```

So really, when we're passing `factory: :user`, what we're really doing is passing `{factory: :user}`, also written as `{:factory => :user}`. The 1.9 syntax is intended to make it easier to do something like `{factory: "user"}`

Comment: I feel this is a much better way to specify a hash (I might be biased since come from python dicts though). Even from the perspective of POLA and programmer-happiness that ruby and RoR so enthusiastically endorse, the typing-heavy hashrocket was a sore thumb in my opinion. Good that we have an option of using colon notation now.