# What's the difference `{'x'=> 3}` and `{x: 3}`?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
a = {'x' => 3}
b = {'x': 3}
c = {x: 3}
d = {:x => 3}
e = {:'x' => 3}
```

So, I have that `b = c = d = e = {:x => 3}`, meanwhile `a = {"x" => 3}` but `a.class == b.class`.

I don't understand what the difference is between `a` and the rest of variables.

Comment: What is the `class=` method used in `a.class = b.class`?

Comment: sorry, I ment, the boolean validation between both object class is true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ruby what is the meaning of colon after identifier in a Hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645668/in-ruby-what-is-the-meaning-of-colon-after-identifier-in-a-hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `b`,`c`,`d`, and `e`, the key is a [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Symbol.html).

In `a`, the key is a [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html).

```
a = { 'x' => 3 }  #=> { "x" => 3 } 
b = { 'x': 3 }    #=> { :x => 3 }
c = { x: 3 }      #=> { :x => 3 }
d = { :x => 3 }   #=> { :x => 3 }
e = { :'x' => 3 } #=> { :x => 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `a` hash has `"x"` key as a string, while other variables have that key as symbol.

Calling `class` on an object in Ruby returns its class, in your example it is `Hash`. In other words, the constructor of all hash instances, such as `{x: 3}` is `Hash` object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a significant difference between [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html) and [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Symbol.html) classes in ruby:

- [explanation on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255078/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-symbol-in-ruby);
- [good article on the topic](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/ruby-similarity-and-difference-between-symbol-and-string-with-facts/).

By convention, all but the very first hash notations cast keys to the `Symbol` instance, while the first one uses the key (`String` instance in this particular case) as is. (To be more precise: `b` and `c` cast key to the `Symbol` instance, `d` and `e` do not cast anything, but keys given in these cases are `Symbol` instances already.)

Since `('x' == :x) == false`, `a` hash differs from the latters.